# How to make a single line GET method asynchronous?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

Best practices dictates that asynchronous access to the database should be mandatory, however I'm not being able to do it in a GET method:

```
public class DataRepository
{
    private ContextDb _contextDb;

    public DataRepository(ContextDb dbInstance)
    {
        _contextDb = dbInstance;
    }
    //--------GETs----------
    public async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<Answer>> GetAnswers()
    {
        return _contextDb.Answers.AsAsyncEnumerable();
    }
```

The issue in the above GetAnswers() is that I can't place the "await" operator neither before or after the "return", and so at the moment this runs synchronously.

Previously the method was like this:

```
public Answer[] GetAnswers()
    {
        return _contextDb.Answers.ToArray();
    }
```

What would be the correct way to convert this to an async method? And should it be implemented in this case?

Comment: `Best practices dictates that asynchronous access to the database should be mandatory` -- Citation, please.

Comment: Can't you simply remove `async` keyword? If `AsAsyncEnumerable` is returning a task, isn't that enough? Also, why can't you add the `await` keyword after the `return` keyword? What is stopping you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen)
's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70620969/how-to-make-a-single-line-get-method-asynchronous/70621141#comment124840458_70620969):

> Can't you simply remove `async` keyword? If `AsAsyncEnumerable` is returning a task, isn't that enough? Also, why can't you add the `await` keyword after the `return` keyword? What is stopping you?

I removed the async keyword and it works now:

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<Answer> GetAnswers()
{
    return _contextDb.Answers.AsAsyncEnumerable();
}
```

I checked in the following link and indeed it works like I want this way (didn't know async programming could be done without `async` or `await`).

[Microsoft IAsyncEnumerable Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30784876)

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak - this was an answer, not a request for information.